How do I programmatically run a query against Salesforce Marketing Cloud
I am trying to automate the extraction of data from some Data Extensions within Salesforce Marketing Cloud (formerly Exact Target).
Currently, there are queries being run from within the Query Studio (e.g.
select distinct CompositeKey as ActivityCompositeKey, Type, BounceCategory from SendLogAnalyticsForExport where Type='EmailSent'
)
How do I do this from within an externally run process (that I will be writing, ideally in C#)?
I have credentials to connect to the marketing cloud apis as well as the AuthN and REST and SOAP URL
AuthURL: https://XXXXXXXXXXX.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token
ClientId: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ClientSecret: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
SoapURL: https://XXXXXXXXXXX.soap.marketingcloudapis.com
RestURL: https://XXXXXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com


I have looked into the documentation for the "Marketing Cloud Engagement APIs and SDKs" and found the REST API and SOAP API. But there's nothing specifically geared at running a query in the form specified above (i.e. SQL-like query that can be run from within the Query Studio).
The closest thing I saw was the documentation for "Query Data using Query API V1" within the Salesforce "Data Cloud Reference Guide"; however, this also does not seem to be targeted at Marketing Cloud (also, the explanations were rather scant: nothing about the actual endpoints to hit, no info about the authentication method).
In addition, I have looked at the FuelSDK-CSharp library. But, once again, nothing specifically geared at running a SQL-like query against Data Extensions.

You can create a Query Activity and place it in an Automation and then invoke the Automation via API. After the Automation runs, you can retrieve the contents of the Data Extension, or have the Automation deliver the DE's contents to a fileserver of your choosing.
If you need to alter your Query, there is an API to do that, but you will also need to revise the DE's schema to match as well.
More info here:
https://gortonington.com/how-to-interact-with-query-activities-via-rest-api/
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api.html
https://gortonington.com/sfmc-custom-de-retrieve-rest-api-endpoint/
